# Small conditional probabilies textbook question

Tags: self-study, bayes

I have an example from a book I am working through (car starting problem, with fuel & dirty spark plugs), but need a little help please.

We have probabilities: P(NS) = 0.016, P(NF) = 0.001, P(F) = 0.999,  P(SPD) = 0.05 and P(SPC) = 0.95.

Where S = car starts, NS = car doesn't start, F = there is fuel in car, NF = there is no fuel in car, SPD = spark plugs are dirty and SPC = spark plugs are clean.

And probabilities:

```
........   NS   S
NF   SPD   1    0
NF   SPC   1    0
F    SPD   0.1  0.9
F    SPC   0.01 0.99
```

(So for example, the first row: if the car has no fuel (NF) and spark plugs are dirtty (SPD) the car will not start with probability one)

I want to calculate P(SPD|NS).

My attempt:

```
P(SPD|NS) = P(SPD and NS) / P(NS) = P(NS|SPD)P(SPD) / P(NS)
```

So I need P(NS|SPD) – need for all fuel status (F or NF).

I think this should be = 1*0.001 + 0.1*0.999.

I am going in circles trying to write the above line as probabilities – what is the proper way to present this in terms of NS, SPD, F and NF (assuming it is right). 
Thanks.

Comment: I formatted your table, but I cannot help you explain what it means nor can I explain what the abbreviations "NS" etc. mean (although of course I could guess, but my guesses might be inaccurate).  Please edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to derive $P(NS|SPD)$ from your table.

Notice, $P(NS|SPD) = \sum_{F}P(NS, F|SPD) = \sum_{F}P(NS|F,SPD)P(F|SPD) = \sum_{F}P(NS|F,SPD)P(F)$ because having fuel or dirty spark plugs are independent events.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think you need to have some a priori probabilities for having fuel or not and having clean spark plugs or not.  For example, if both are 50/50 (i.e 0.5), the overall probability for each of the four situations is each 0.25, and you can multiply 0.25 by the probabilities for each outcome (starting or not) for the overall probabilities of each situation/outcome combination.  Those numbers can be summed by outcome to create overall outcome probabilities which go into your (I believe) exactly correct formula.

As you might guess, increasing the a priori probability of having fuel increases the information provided by the non-starting car.  When both are relatively likely, the non-start barely gives a probability of dirty over 50%.

Comment: MikeP; Thanks for your help. There are priors for fuel and spark plugs given in the second paragraph. (Big) I think, P(NS|SPD) =  1*0.001 + 0.1*0.999 is correct but i would like to express it, along the lines of P(NS|SPD and F)P(F) + P(NS|SPC and NF)P(NF) - but correctly.

Comment: Sorry I missed that!!!!

Comment: Utilizing the probabilities given, P(NS|SPD) = P(NS&SPD)/P(SPD) = 0.005045 / 0.05000 = 0.1009 or about 10%